# How to handle network error using java gRPC client with blocking stub?

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I'm using java `gRPC` blocking stub to make domain requests to other service (let's call it Server):

```java
private final DomainServiceGrpc.DomainServiceBlockingStub stub;

public void send(final dto) {
    DomainResponse response = stub.sendDomain(dto);
    LOG.info(String.format("Received response: %s", response));
}
```

Sometimes the Server unavailable and when I send request I receive the next Runtime Exception:

```java
2022-05-13 16:22:15.115  WARN 7 --- [ault-executor-1] io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl      : [Channel<1>: (hostname:9090)] 
Failed to resolve name. status=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host hostname, 
cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: hostname: Temporary failure in name resolution
at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:223)
at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.doResolve(DnsNameResolver.java:282)
at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:318)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: hostname: Temporary failure in name resolution
at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1519)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1368)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1302)
at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:631)
at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:219)
... 5 more
```

which actually terminates my working thread and new messages won't be sent.
I definetely have to handle the network exception and the only way I have found is using plain `try/catch`:

```java
try {
    DomainResponse response = stub.sendDomain(dto);
    LOG.info(String.format("Received response: %s", response));
} catch (Throwable ignore) {
}
```

which seems inappropriate for that case because I have to write `try/catch` for each `gRPC` method.
Does some graceful method exist for `gRPC` network exception handling on client side?

Comment: It is better to catch `StatusRuntimeException` instead of `Throwable`. This is what is done in the gRPC Hello World example. https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/c6bfce034f00009838f37a08dd1a27638a7b74b7/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldClient.java#L51

Answer (score 0):

In gRPC, calls are "fail fast" by default, which means that in the event of a network failure, the call will be treated as a failure.   You can override this behavior on the stub (via the `CallOptions` to not wait for ready, which tells the RPC to keep trying on other connections until it succeeds.   Make sure to set a deadline for the RPC, or else it may get stuck a long time waiting for a connection to enter the `READY` state.

See https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/wait-for-ready.md

Comment: I've tried your proposed solution but it didn't override the behavior. Could you take a look at the changes that I've made to the blocking stub at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78095587/how-to-suppress-unknownhostexception-at-runtime-in-a-java-grpc-client ?  Thanks!