# How to suppress UnknownHostException at runtime in a Java gRPC client

Tags: grpc-java

A service request is issued to some unresolvable host using the following java gRPC blocking stub:

```
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("SomeUnknownHost", 12345)
                                                .usePlaintext()
                                                .build();
    MyServiceGrpc.MyServiceBlockingStub clientStub;
    clientStub = MyServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
    clientStub.increment(Message.newBuilder()
                                .setNumber(1)
                                .build());
```

This causes an `UnknownHostException` thrown at runtime:

```
Mar 03, 2024 2:43:02 A.M. io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener handleErrorInSyncContext
WARNING: [Channel<1>: (SomeUnknownHost:12345)] Failed to resolve name. status=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host UnknownHostException, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: foobar: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:223)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.doResolve(DnsNameResolver.java:282)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:318)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: SomeUnknownHost: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:52)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformResolver.lookupByName(InetAddress.java:1059)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1673)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:1003)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1663)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1528)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:632)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:219)
    ... 5 more
```

Carl Mastrangelo explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72232854/how-to-handle-network-error-using-java-grpc-client-with-blocking-stub) that:

> In gRPC, calls are "fail fast" by default, which means that in the
> event of a network failure, the call will be treated as a failure. You
> can override this behavior on the stub

```
public static final class MyServiceBlockingStub extends io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub<MyServiceBlockingStub> {
    private MyServiceBlockingStub(io.grpc.Channel channel) {
      super(channel);
    }

    private MyServiceBlockingStub(io.grpc.Channel channel,
        io.grpc.CallOptions callOptions) {
      super(channel, callOptions.withWaitForReady());
    }

    @java.lang.Override
    protected MyServiceBlockingStub build(io.grpc.Channel channel,
        io.grpc.CallOptions callOptions) {
      //System.out.println("WAIT-FOR-READY IS ON: " + callOptions.withWaitForReady().isWaitForReady());

      return new MyServiceBlockingStub(channel, callOptions.withWaitForReady());
    }

    public Message increment(Message request) {
      System.out.println("WAIT-FOR-READY IS ON: " + getCallOptions().withWaitForReady().isWaitForReady()); // TRUE
      return blockingUnaryCall(
          getChannel(), getIncrementMethod(), getCallOptions().withWaitForReady(), request);
    }
}
```

The proposed solution was to enable the Wait-for-Ready call option in the client stub.  So I tried making those changes but an `UnknownHostException` is still thrown at runtime.

What do I need to do to suppress `UnknownHostException` at runtime in a Java gRPC client?

Comment: Why not simply use try-catch block specifically targeting `UnknownHostException` exception?

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub How?
As shown above,
```io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener handleErrorInSyncContext

WARNING: [Channel<1>: (SomeUnknownHost:12345)] Failed to resolve name. status=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable ...
...
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: SomeUnknownHost: nodename nor servname provided, or not known```

How do I find the location to where I should insert the try-catch block to target those specific exceptions?

Comment: I'll be equally happy with someone showing me how to disable the logger warnings, enabled [on this line](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/ac62c8b055cc415f7d8b17edad6abcb3ade548cf/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/internal/ManagedChannelImpl.java#L1908), for this `UnknownHostException`.

Comment: I managed to disable the relevant log messages via LogManager.  Though, I must say that it'd a lot easier if grpc-java had a more user-friendly api for controlling both its failure and logging behaviours.

Comment: Please continue to leave this question open as its original intent was to investigate why enabling Wait-for-Ready call option doesn't stop UnknnowHostException from being thrown as expected.

Javadoc:
> "Wait-for-ready queues the RPC *until a connection is available*. This may dramatically increase the latency of the RPC, but avoids failing 'unnecessarily'".

Comment: Do you expect the host becomes available in some time?